# How to create Sequence number based on two variables together

Tags: sas

I have the following dataset :

```
 ID   CODE  
 1     A
 1     B  
 2     A  
 2     A  
 2     B  
 3     A  
 3     B
```

I would like to add a third column to this table which gives a sequence no. as given below :

```
 ID   CODE  SEQ
 1     A     1
 1     B     2
 2     A     1
 2     A     1
 2     B     2
 3     A     1
 3     B     2
```

How can I achieve this instead of coding A as 1 and B as 2 rather by a retain statement ?

Answer (score 2):

You should look at by processing and `first.`.  Something like this will work; basically, for each ID initialize seq to zero, and for each new code increment it by one.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by id code;
  if first.id then seq=0;
  if first.code then seq+1;
run;
```